# Splitting Python module into many files

Tags: django, python-3.x

My Python module has become too big. So instead of a single file

### paradigms.py

```
class Hub: ...
class Virement: ...
class Bond: ...
class Credit: ...
```

I'd like to have a directory `paradigms`, with two files in it:

### transfer.py

```
class Hub: ...
class Virement: ...
```

### credit.py

```
class Bond: ...
class Credit: ...
```

(Of course, both the number of files, and the number of classes in a file, are much bigger.)

The problem is that I would like to continue using `paradigms` like I have been before:

```
import paradigms
paradigms.Hub(...).clear()
```

or

```
from paradigms import Credit
```

or even

```
from paradigms import *
```

So, in a way, I would like `transfer` and `credit` names to disappear in an external interface, and my module (I guess now it is a package) to appear to the outside like a single module. Can this be done relatively easily?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a `paradigms` package, containing your two modules `transfer.py` and `credit.py`, importing their classes to the package
level in `__init__.py`:

```
paradigms/
    __init__.py
    credit.py
    transfer.py
```

`__init__.py` would be:

```
from credit import *
from transfer import *
```

You can then do:

```
import paradigms
paradigms.Bond
```

etc.

Comment: Ah yes. It was too simple for me to think about it. :-D I got stuck reading about namespace packages and other wonders.